# DryIoC - Register equivalent in Unity Prism

Tags: xamarin, unity-container, prism, dryioc

What is the equivalent of this code(DryIoC) in Unity?

```
Container.Register<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>( Reuse.Singleton );
```

This is a sample code from [HamburgerMenu project in Prism Xamarin](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Forms/blob/master/HamburgerMenu/HamburgerMenu/App.xaml.cs)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>( new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager() );
```

That means that the lifetime of the `AuthenticationService` will match the lifetime of the container. If you don't destroy and recreate the container, you'll always get the same service instance.